# IIS 7.5 Bind to IP address with shared configuration

Tags: ssl, iis, https, iis-7.5, bindings

We have two web sites hosted on IIS that we want to SSL.  To do this I believe we need each site to have their own IP address.

These sites are hosted on a web farm which is load balanced with a hardware load balancer. Each server in the farm is set up with shared configuration.

So, if we have two sites, each server needs two IP addresses.  The issue is with shared configuration how do we set up the site bindings, because the same site on each server will be bound to a different IP?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. Easier than you think. You have to logon to both servers to bind the SSL, but create the bindings from the 1st one. Use the internal IP and create the SSL binding for the internal IP. You can manually type in the 2nd IP that doesn't exist on the first server. Then login and ensure that the 2nd IP has a cert associated with it. You of course have the LB IP, but that is external to the server. The server should have bindings for its internal IP for both HTTP and HTTPS. The load balancer is independent of this config.